# How does the Codepen fixed menu work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, codepen

When using Codepen on a mobile device (with the pen in fullscreen mode), the menu stays fixed at the top of the page while the rest of the content scrolls behind it. On inspecting the element, there does not seem to be any position:fixed or position:absolute being set nor any inline styles being written by Javascript. I can't see any properties which would seem to be defining this behaviour.

So how have they made the menu sticky like this? And if you were able to find out: how did you find out? As a junior dev it's just as helpful to know the way a solution was found as it is to know the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show us at least a screenshot of what you are trying to reproduce and a sample of what you have tried so far ?

If you looked a little more in detail, you'd see that the view is inside an `iframe`, so the scrolling actually occurs **inside** the iframe, that's why the menu holds still on top. You could have noticed that the scrollbar is actually *inside* the `iframe` too.

See the image below:
[image]

Comment: Ah yes, was so carefully investigating the header that I did not think to look at the main content - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider closing the thread if it's all good now :)